# How do I get the serial port number my Arduino is connected to?

Tags: python, arduino-uno

I'm trying to use PyFirmata to code my Arduino Uno, but it requires the port my board is connected to.  I tried out checking device manager, but it doesn't show the URL address, which is what PyFirmata requires.

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: a simple hack is to install arduino and check from there and define it as `serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)`

Comment: can you show a code example?

Comment: sorry, I used `pyserial` instead of  `PyFirmata`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the path by first connecting the arduino and raspberry pi via USB. Then, on the raspberry pi's terminal, make sure you are current in the home directory (if you open a new terminal window, you will most likely be home), and enter:

```
ls /dev
```

This should show you the content inside "dev", there should be an entry that resembles "ttyACM0" / "ttyACM1". That is the path to the USB port on the raspberry pi, which will give you access to the Arduino connected to it.